# In C programming, can separate processes in the same program share the same address space? What about threads sharing space in the same process?

Tags: c, multithreading

Can separate processes in the same program share the same address? And can threads in the same process share the same address space?

Thank you.

Comment: C knows nothing about address space

Comment: Thanks to MMU-magic, two different processes can both use the same *virtual address* and it will map to two different *physical addresses*.  E.g. process A might do `int a = *((int *)0x6000);` and (assuming 0x6000 is a valid address in A's virtual-address space) get one value assigned to `a`, and process B might also do `int b = *((int *)0x6000);` and retrieve a completely different value.  It's not clear if that counts as "sharing the same address" or not.

Comment: Please say more about what you think "processes in the same program" means (e.g., do you mean different _invocations_ of the same program?) Also, please say more about "share the same address." Do you mean to ask whether different processes can share _some_ virtual addresses? Or are you asking whether they can share their _entire_ address space? And finally, what _operating system_ are you asking about? (@phuclv is right. Even though some C toolchains still give one the ability to access specific addresses, this question does not appear to ask anything about the C programming language.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not at all sure what you mean by "separate processes in the same program ", if you mean separate instances of the same program then yes, in modern operating systems it is possible for processes (whether or not running the same binary) to share memory (whether or not mapped to the same address). That is simply a matter of how the OS loads stuff into memory. For example, shared libraries will usually only have a single instance of the actual code in physical memory, even if those pages are mapped to different addresses in different programs. Or the program might create a shared memory region in order to share in-memory data with other processes.

For the second part of your question, on most computer architectures any thread can access any address in the program's address space equally with any other thread. There are architectures where this is not the case, called NUMA (non-uniform memory access), where for threads running on specific CPUs some addresses are more costly (in terms of time) to access than others. Though I know they exist, I do not have any personal experience with such systems.